How to change year text value date-picker in vuetify 3?
I would like to know if there is a way to edit the text value
of the years in v-date-picker in vuetify 3?
I would like to add 'test' string beside the year value.
So instead of only '2021' it would be '2021test'
Please see image to fully understand the question.
see image

Consider explaining your case. What exactly is really "test" and under which condition is it supposed to occur? The answer may depend on this. Basically the picker is hard-coded to use this component, and this place is responsible for this https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/blob/master/packages/vuetify/src/components/VDatePicker/VDatePickerYears.tsx#L76 , so in least comfortable approach you'd have to fork it and other linked modules. The solution can be better depending on what this is all about

Maybe something like this: vuetify-play
  <template>
  <v-app>
    <v-container>
      <v-date-picker></v-date-picker>
    </v-container>
  </v-app>
</template>

<style>
  .v-date-picker-years .v-btn__content::after {
    content: ' Test';
  }
</style>


